# Firefox does not animate navigation of react website when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox

I've built a navigation that hides whenever the user scrolls down and comes back into view when the user scrolls up. This works perfectly on Chrome and Safari but not on Firefox. On Firefox the navigation does not do anything except when I hover over it with the inspect element tool.

Running React 16.9. I've tried the following things.

Tested on newest versions of chrome and firefox.

- Tried using a requestAnimationFrame
- Using rotate3d so the gpu takes over
- Checked if scroll event fires ( it does. )
- Tried same animation with opacity instead of changing top

Some code:

// The event listener is added

```
  componentDidMount = () => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', throttle(this.handleScroll, 100));
    window.addEventListener('keyup', this.handleKeyPress);
  }
```

// What the event fires

```
  handleScroll = () => {
    const { currentNodeType } = this.props;
    if (currentNodeType === 'landing_page') {
      this.setState({ navScrolled: window.scrollY > (window.innerHeight - 125) });
    } else {
      this.setState({ navScrolled: window.scrollY > 285 });
    }
    const { prevScrollpos } = this.state;

    const currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
    const visible = !!(prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos || window.scrollY < 30);

    this.setState({
      prevScrollpos: currentScrollPos,
      visible,
    });
  }
```

A class is then added or removed to the navigation depending on if its visible

// The classes

```css
.nav-hidden {
  transition: all 0.333s ease-out;
  top: -125px;
}
.nav-visible {
  transition: all 0.333s ease-out;
  top: 0;
}
```

I can't post images because of rep needed. ( this is my first question on stack overflow )

behaviour on chrome - desired behaviour

https://imgur.com/WkhlS4Y.gif

behaviour on firefox - undesired behaviour

https://imgur.com/hoEOP4x.gif

I hope I've been clear enough. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by using margin instead of top.

```
.nav-hidden {
  transition: all 0.333s ease-out;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: -125px;
}
.nav-visible {
  transition: all 0.333s ease-out;
  top: 0;
}
```

Hope this helps!